# python script messes up %time% in batchfile

Tags: python, batch-file, windows-7

I am working with a batchfile, where I regularly write the time for performance monitoring purposes. This worked well but recently I have called a Python script within that batchfile and the time measurement seems not to work anymore:
My batchfile looks as follows:

```
echo [%TIME%] -- task 1
<perform task 1>
echo [%TIME%] -- task 2
<perform task 2>
echo [%TIME%] -- finished
```

, giving following results:

```
[14:51:32.97] -- task 1
[14:51:34.32] -- task 2
[14:51:39.07] -- finished
```

Now I have replaced  by a Python script (which takes at least some minutes), but my %TIME% variable seems not to be updated anymore:

```
echo [%TIME%] -- task 1
<perform task 1>
echo [%TIME%] -- task 2
python task2.py
echo [%TIME%] -- finished
```

gives following result:

```
[14:51:40.02] -- task 1
[14:51:44.32] -- task 2
[14:51:44.32] -- finished
```

Does anybody know what might cause this issue and how to solve it?
For your information, I'm working on a virtual Windows 7 system, and my Python installation is version 3.5.0.

Comment: Is that your actual code, or are you leaving some bits out? Because I can almost guarantee that you've got `%TIME%` inside of a set of parentheses and that's why it isn't updating.

Comment: Try `call echo [%%time%%]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this issue is not 'python-related'. For example the script

```
@echo off

echo [%TIME%] ---
echo [%TIME%] ping1
ping 8.8.8.8 >nul
echo [%TIME%] ping1 done

if not exist 123 (
echo [%TIME%] ping2
ping 8.8.8.8 >nul
echo [%TIME%] ping2 done
)

echo [%TIME%] ping3
ping 8.8.8.8 >nul
echo [%TIME%] ping3 done
echo [%TIME%] ---
```

will output

```
[20:33:32,00] ---
[20:33:32,00] ping1
[20:33:35,04] ping1 done
[20:33:35,04] ping2
[20:33:35,04] ping2 done
[20:33:38,12] ping3
[20:33:41,16] ping3 done
[20:33:41,16] ---
```

As you can see `ping2` and `ping2 done` have the same time stamp. When using parenthesis `(` `)` the CMD shell will expand [read] all the variables at the beginning of the code block and use those values even if the variables value is changed within the code block.

So in this case the solution is

```
if not exist 123 (
call echo [%%TIME%%] ping2
ping 8.8.8.8 >nul
call echo [%%TIME%%] ping2 done
)
```

or

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
...
if not exist 123 (
echo [!TIME!] ping2
ping 8.8.8.8 >nul
echo [!TIME!] ping2 done
)
```

and output is

```
[20:45:28,45] ---
[20:45:28,45] ping1
[20:45:31,49] ping1 done
[20:45:31,49] ping2
[20:45:34,53] ping2 done
[20:45:34,54] ping3
[20:45:37,59] ping3 done
[20:45:37,59] ---
```